# How to theme a flag for different pages?

Tags: 7, theming, flags

I want to theme a flag for different pages like on user profile page the html of the flag will be different then on the view page . I can make  use of the flag.tpl.php and theme it but, I don't how to theme it for different pages.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work for user pages. You can adapt for other pages. Put it in your theme's template.php file.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_flag(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['flag']->name == "MACHINE_NAME_OF_FLAG") {
    if (arg(0) == 'user') {
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'flag__user_page';
    }
  }
}
```

and the template file name then becomes

```
flag--user-page.tpl.php
```

Answer (score 1):

In the display option of the flag (admin/structure/flags/manage/yourflag =>#DISPLAY OPTIONS), you can check "Display link as field". then you will find your flag display option in admin/config/people/accounts/display. If you use the module [field formatter class](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_formatter_class) you can specify a class just for the field display in the user profile.

It is also possible to display flags button and flags result using [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) which allows you to add a specific class as well.